# Synchronous base method with async override

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a base class whose children may want to implement a method 
 asynchronously.
I have implemented as below, however Visual Studio suggests making `GetEntityName` in the base synchronous because it doesn't `await` anything. This however would break the children.

Is there a better way?

```
  public abstract class BaseHandler
  {
        protected virtual async Task<string> GetEntityName(object entity)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
  }



 public class ChilldHandler: BaseHandler
 {
        protected override async Task<string> GetEntityName(object entity)
        {
            return await LongRunningService.DoSomething(entity);
        }
 }
```

Comment: The base class requires an implementation. Inheriting classes do not have to implement it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public abstract class BaseHandler
{
    protected virtual Task<string> GetEntityName(object entity)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Because your method doesn't do anything that can be awaited, you can return already finished Task, by using `Task.FromResult` method.

You don't need to await anything inside `GetEntityName`, because there isn't any incomplete Task to be awaited.

Answer (score 4):

`async` is an *implementation detail* of the specific method on which it appears. Despite where it appears, it does *not* form part of the method signature. (This is also why you're not allowed `async` in interfaces<sup>1</sup> - because they have no implementation and it's not part of the method signature).

Which is to say, any virtual `Task` returning method may have `override` implementations in child classes that do/do not make use of `async` and it's irrelevant how the original base method was marked either.

[As FCin shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54201253/15498), it's perfectly possibly to have a synchronous method still returning the `Task` that you want as the return type for the method.

---

<sup>1</sup>Ignoring new-fangled default implementations for interfaces.

Comment: Although this is entirely true, the return type which **is** part of the signature tends to show the method is used in an asynchronous context.

Comment: @vc74 - returning a `Task` or `Task<T>` is enough to allow the method to be called from an async context. It doesn't *matter* to the calling code whether the *current* implementation of the method it's calling uses `async` or not, just that the return type is awaitable. You don't `await` `async` methods - you `await` `Task` returning methods. (if what's to the right of `await` is a method at all - the `Task` or awaitable could have come from anywhere)